# reCAPTCHA: Missing POST response for 'g-recaptcha-response'

Tags: javascript, php, recaptcha

We have a live reCaptcha v2 implementation at the following URL:

https://och.stonybrook.edu/index.php?page=roommates&task=submit

The reCaptcha has been working fine until reported to me as not working today.

I have identified the following:

- The reCaptcha JS is loading successfully
- The reCaptcha is working well on the form -- creating the element, checking the box and adding an encrypted string to the g-recaptcha-response textarea element that is created by the library.
- However, on the server I am seeing no value for $_POST['g-recaptcha-response']
- When I var_dump the $_POST array in PHP, I see all other form values but not this one. It does not exist as an index in the $_POST array

I have:

- Verified domain in reCAPTCHA admin
- Created a new site/secret key pair
- Tried the test key pair provided by Google via the docs

I can't get to the bottom of why that `<textarea>` is not posting its data to the server.

I have crawled the docs at https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify to no avail.

**HTML:**

```
<!-- Using the Auto Render implementation as described in 
https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display#auto_render -->

<!-- in <head> -->
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js"></script>

<!-- in <form> -->
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="SITE_KEY"></div>
```

**PHP:**

```
echo($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']); //outputs nothing

var_dump($_POST); //outputs all of my form values, except for <textarea id="g-recaptcha-response">
```

Comment: We can't see your code from here...

Comment: we also can't see the page at that URL in the link, gets redirect to a login page instead

Comment: I have removed the authentication. Try now.

Answer (score 1):

The form is most likely malformed e.g. mis-matched HTML tags. Inspect within chrome and make sure the form wraps around the captcha textarea.

Comment: I am implementing reCaptcha v2 on a very old site (not created by me). In my case the html was indeed malformed. Thanks.